# Parentheses for $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \prod_{j=1}^i(y_j + \alpha)$

Tags: notation

I am typesetting an equation of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\Bigl(x_i \prod_{j=1}^i(y_j + \alpha) \Bigr)$$
Originally, I wrote the equation without the outer pair of parentheses, and a reviewer asked me to include them. I agree that they improve the legibility of the equation. But are these parentheses **strictly necessary**?

In my opinion, the fact that the inner product depends on $i$ rules out any alternative interpretation of
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \prod_{j=1}^i(y_j + \alpha) $$
For that reason, my preference is to include the outer parentheses on the first mention and exclude them from subsequent uses of this equation. Is this a reasonable solution?

Comment: As you mentioned, the parentheses are not **strictly** necessary, but I would include them anyway. If you do that, you draw the attention to the fact that the upper limit in the product depends on $i$.

Comment: If you’re going to use parentheses here, you should use \left( and \right) to size them properly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about mathematics. That said, I say keep the parentheses everywhere. That makes life easier for your readers, which is the purpose of good notation.

Comment: @EthanBolker There are currently 11,500 questions in the [notation] tag on this site. If you think that this tag is off-topic, then this is an issue for meta.

Comment: @RobPratt, I am reverting your spurious edit changing "parentheses" to "brackets" in my title. Changing [American usage to British usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168762/brackets-vs-parenthesis) and vice-versa is considered bad practice on this site: [meta link 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23872/495885) [meta link 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305446/495885)

Comment: @Max I didn’t change to brackets. I corrected $y_i$ to $y_j$.

Comment: @RobPratt Indeed, I am a fool: I had made the change myself and forgotten about it. My apologies.

Comment: No problem. I am American, so I would have changed it *from* brackets. :)